# Do kernel components like the scheduler execute on their own dedicated CPU/Core or do they share?

Tags: windows, scheduler

Can someone explain how the Windows scheduler executes its code. Does it work from a dedicated CPU or does it share with all other kernel mode/user mode processes ? I have read somewhere that modern day processors  offer architectural extensions providing for several banks of registers that can be swapped in hardware [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782388/how-dispatcher-works).

Comment: What would happen if you had only one processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They share.  A typical system spends so little of its time running kernel code that dedicating an entire core to it would be an absurd waste, and the scheduler itself is a tiny fraction even of that.  And in cases where it does need to run a lot of kernel code, that's exactly when you *want* that work shared among as many cores as possible.

I'm not sure about Windows specifically, but a common OS design is that *every* core executes the scheduler when it's time to decide which task *that core* should execute next.